# Firefox extension ported to Safari, Permission Warning " This extension can read and alter ewb pages you visit...."

Tags: javascript, safari, permissions, manifest, safari-extension

I have this warning appearing in my safari extension preferences. However I have tried removing every single part of the permissions in the manifest.json of the safari extension however no luck.

This extension was created using the xCode tool to port the firefox extension to safari.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer after constant researching into this;

Initially with extensions it will not show the warning banner.

However if your website requires access to the webpage using content.js, then safari will pop up with this warning message to the user:

[image]

If the user clicks on **Always Allow on This Website**, then the warning message will not appear however what will appear is:

[image]

This just highlights a list of all the websites that you have individually accepted access to.

However if you decide just to let the extension have access to **ALL** webpages then the following warning will then appear:

[image]

**So it doesn't seem that it is possible to remove this message, as it's a safari-focused message**

Comment: However it is definitely interesting how extensions such as Honey, Grammarly etc do not show this message even after having the same permissions.